# My 14' weeping willow tree's pruned main branch is growing off center

Tags: trees, weeping-willow

I pruned the main branch of my (7') weeping willow tree last year too low (I'm guessing) and now the main branch is about 3-5" off center. The tree is now about 12-14' high.

Is this a problem? If so, how do I correct it?

[image: the photo is slanted. Tilt your head to the right to view. The highest top right branch is the one growing off-canter]

Comment: Normally willows grow so much that three inches won't be noticed but a picture would help.

Answer (score 2):

Now that there is a photo to work from I feel confident that this is not a problem. Yes, it probably would have been better to leave a leader but with the fast growth willows have one branch will end up becoming the new leader. I think one of the side branches is already tending upwards.  It just needs a little help. See [here](http://pubs.ext.vt.edu/430/430-456/430-456.html) for corrective pruning practices which include

> replace it by splinting an upper lateral on the highest scaffold to a
>   vertical position. Prune all laterals immediately below the new
>   leader. Use wood or flexible wire splints, removing them after one
>   growing season.

In general you should follow these points with [weeping willows (Salix babylonica)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salix_babylonica):

- prune young trees in late winter to encourage a strong growth habit. They grow wide and spread with many arching branches and multiple trunks. Since the wood is weak, breaking and splitting damages the tree at the weakest points
- remove V-shaped crotches where limbs and trunk fork as these are the weakest points
- select a central stem for the tree's leader and remove any competing vertical growth.

Something else to keep in mind is that weeping willows get quite large (20–25 m  or 66–82 ft). They have brittle wood and drop branches all the time.  This is not a plant you want close to your house or near anything that can be damaged by something large and heavy falling on it.

Comment: @kevinsy: thank you so much for the very helpful information.  :)